# How to execute the adb commands in python scripts

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I have the below Details:

list =[' otpackagename1','packagename2','packagename3'...]

I need to excecute the command as below.

os.system('adb install packagename1') till the list value n

please help me in this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. Just use a loop!

```
for x in list:
     os.system("adb install " + x)
```

That's it!

Also, for this to work, you need adb to be added to your PATH variable.
For information regarding how to do it, [see here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=add+adb+to+path).